# em R, criar uma função de arrendondamento de vetores de maneira que as coordenadas somem 100

Tags: r

Eu tenho um vector de percentuais, por exemplo,

```
v<- c(32.5 , 43.2 , 24.1)
> round(v)
[1] 32 43 24
> sum(round(v))
[1] 99
```

Eu quero uma função que manipule o meu arrendondamento de maneira que some 100. Em outras palavras, quero uma função `fun` de maneira que `sum(fun(v))=100`.
O critério, claro, tem que ser de maneira que cada coordenada de `fun(v)` se afaste o menos possível dos valores originais. Alguém conhece algum método para fazer isto?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792460/how-to-round-floats-to-integers-while-preserving-their-sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que seja isso o que procura:

```
x1=32.5
x2=43.2
if (x1-trunc(x1)>=.5) {y1=trunc(x1)+1} else y1=trunc(x1)
if (x2-trunc(x2)>=.5) {y2=trunc(x2)+1} else y2=trunc(x2)
y3=100-(y1+y2)
v=c(y1,y2,y3)
v
sum(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Não acredito que exista uma maneira objetiva (não-subjetiva) de se fazer isso. Imagine o seguinte cenário:

```
> v <- c(rep(10.1, 9), 9.1)
> sum(v)
[1] 100
> sum(round(v))
[1] 99
```

Qual valor do vetor `round(v)` você alteraria para `sum(round(v))` ser igual a 100?

A melhor solução seria utilizar os valores sem arredondamento. Se não for possível, baseado no que você achar razoável, verificar manualmente qual número deve ser alterado ou criar uma função que faça isso.

Comment: Talvez medindo as distâncias entre o seu arredondamento de uma e zero casas decimais. Fazer algum tipo de minimização dessas diferenças.

Comment: Uma minimização resolveria alguns casos, mas acho que não resolveria todos. No caso acima, por exemplo, não consegui pensar em nada. Como você minimizaria?

Comment: Aqui há um método http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_remainder_method

Answer (score 0):

Já deu uma olhada nas funções `floor` e `ceiling`? Já precisei disso que você está atras eu fazia algo desse tipo:

```
> v<- c(32.5 , 43.2 , 24.1)
> v
[1] 32.5 43.2 24.1
> sum(v)
[1] 99.8
> ceiling(sum(v))
[1] 100
```

Você pode variar a aplicação do ceiling e usar o floor no somatório, há varias formas de fazer isso. Até mesmo com o `round` e outras função de arredondamento base do R:

```
ceiling(x)
floor(x)
trunc(x, ...)
round(x, digits = 0)
signif(x, digits = 6)
```

Comment: Acho que não fui muito claro na minha pergunta, mas eu quero uma função fun que me de cada coordenada de v sem casas decimais e que ao somar me de 100, ou seja sum(fun(v)) = 100. Jà arrumei a minha pergunta. Mesmo assim, não conheço esse pacote e vou ver se da para fazer alguma coisa

Comment: @Vasco agora entendi, isso é um problema "simples" de otimização. Onde v tem as variáveis e 100 seria o valor já determinado da função objetivo, to sem tempo agora mas depois faço um exemplo pra ti. No excel utilizando o Solver é muito simples fazer isso.

Comment: muito obrigado.. eu prefiro um código o R. Nunca mexi com otimização no R.